# Using pyautogui exclusively for on-screen keyboard

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm looking to make a bot for a game via on-screen keyboard.

Is it possible to make pyautogui execute only on the on-screen keyboard and no other window?

Is there any way to map the buttons into shortcuts that I can easily call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `locateOnScreen()` function to find the coordinates of a button using a screenshot.

Window-specific functions are on the Roadmap (via PyGetWindow), but not implemented in pyautogui yet.

You may be able to check that the coordinates returned by `locateOnScreen()` are within your desired window if you can get the window's rectangle coordinates in some other way, like by calling PyGetWindow's `getWindowsWithTitle()` function yourself.